# Git/Github blame tags push

Tags: git, github, tags

Is it possible to understand who pushed tags to GitHub?

We use Jenkins but there is possibility to push without it, probably git or GitHub can let us know, i found this one but not sure it will help: help .

http://gitHub.com/enterprise/2.5/admin/articles/viewing-push-logs/

thanks in advance

Comment: Is it an annotated tag? Created with `-a` option?

Comment: i will check but question is for general case, in this question I am not the person who push tags, I just want to be awared who did it

Answer (score 2):

You can use `git show <tagname>` to see info like any other commit, but it will only work with an annotated tag (if you used the `-a` option).

Most people recommend to always use annotated tags.

Answer (score 0):

When you set up tags use the `annotated tag`.

Annotated tag is like any other tag but instead ih having just a name it also include full metadata similar to the the commit metadata

The main difference between regular tag to annotate tag is that annotated tag generate full blob (as explained above - same as the commit information)

---

From the git doc.

> ***`-a / --annotate`***
>
> Make an unsigned, annotated tag object

---

If you did use annotated tag the only way to know who creates (now in the present time and not in the past) is to capture the push tag and then grab the committer (the user who push) from it.

Comment: 'If you did use annotated tag the only way to know who creates', did you mean 'unannotated tag' ? I wish solution for all cases : annotated and unannotated